# Rigging: how to set/lock feet IK to follow a global axis?

Tags: rigging

Looking at this youtube video:

[at 3:36] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j7XZ3Q8JNfM

The author has set the feet IKs to "work at a global axis, rather than following the parent armature". He also uses the term "lock to global axis" for the feet at 3:56.

I'm trying to use the same technique for my armature. So how can I set/lock the feet IKs to follow the global axis independently of the parent bones?

Comment: You can add a constraint like limit location to the bones. And it will prevent them from moving along other axes. And you can disable the constraint that makes them child of the root bone (or simply clear parent) - and they will hang in space, no matter what the root does.

Comment: @Mechanic - unfortunately I need to keep the bone a child of the root bone as the whole rig will be exported to Unity with “root motion” enabled for the animations.

Comment: Then you just need to answer yourself the question, what movement exactly do you want, and what you don't. Then, set constraints accordingly. :-)
If you need to follow root, but only along the only axis, the limit location is what you need.